# postgres extract int array from text

Tags: sql, arrays, json, postgresql

I have the following postgresql statement:

```
SELECT 1 = ANY( jsonb_array_elements_text('[2, 1, 3]') );
```

Basically I have a string which contains an array of integers seperated by comma, like: `[1, 2, 3]` and sometimes this array could be empty too, like: `[]`. Now, I want to write a query (as part of a bigger query) where I would be able to find out if an element is matching any integers in the text. For example:

```
SELECT 1 = ANY( jsonb_array_elements_text('[2, 1, 3]') ); -- Should return true
SELECT 1 = ANY( jsonb_array_elements_text('[]') ); -- should return false
```

However, the above query fails with an error message:

```
ERROR:  op ANY/ALL (array) requires array on right side
LINE 1: SELECT 1 = ANY( jsonb_array_elements_text('[2, 1, 3]') );
```

Any help how I can extract an integer array out of a text so that I can use it in a join condition ?

I am using postgres 9.4 if it matters.

Comment: This would be a lot easier with a native integer array rather than JSON: `1 = any(array[1,2,3])`

Comment: Yes, no doubt. But this is part of a bigger query and so I have simplified here for brevity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found it. The answer is:

```
SELECT 1 IN (SELECT json_array_elements('[2, 1, 3]')::text::int);
SELECT 1 IN (SELECT json_array_elements('[]')::text::int);
SELECT 1 IN (SELECT json_array_elements('[12, 10, 3]')::text::int);
```